# Is there a way to see which php.ini values have non-default settings?

Tags: php, configuration, ini, php-ini

I've had to do some archeology on an old PHP 5 server. I've been digging around in the ini files and it occurred to me that it would be very convenient to check which settings have non-default values. I've discovered `php --ini` and `php -r 'php_info();'` and other variants, as well as the [`ini_get_all()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get-all.php), which can show the value set in the php ini files and any overridden value (e.g. from `.htaccess` or `ini_set`).

The php.net documentation describes a default setting [for every ini directive](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php). Is there a way to access these defaults from inside PHP code? That way I could do some simple array manipulations on the return value of `ini_get_all` and pick out which ones have non-default values.

I was looking at [`ini_restore`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-restore.php) and the example given reads as though it only restores to the startup value, i.e. the value configured in the ini files, not the php default value.

Comment: You could get your hands on a fresh download of the PHP version in question and do a diff of the fresh file versus the one currently in use. Be aware that at some point PHP started shipping with a development and production version of the ini file so look for clues in your current ini to see if it says "development" or something.

Comment: Additionally, you could rename your current ini file to something other than `php.ini` and restart PHP so that `ini_get_all` will give you the values which are baked into the core and use [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) on your renamed file.

Comment: This idea is silly... If you were to capture php_info with output buttering, you could then use simplexml to locate the table with the value/default and parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Additionally, you could rename your current ini file to something other than php.ini and restart PHP so that ini_get_all will give you the values which are baked into the core and use parse_ini_file() on your renamed file. – [MonkeyZeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2191572/monkeyzeus)

This worked a charm! Before starting, I had a linked `conf.d` and I had overridden the `cli/php.ini` file to point to the `apache2/php.ini` file so that my php cli invocations would use the web server configs. The `cli/php.ini` file had been renamed `.old`, like so:

```
$ ls -l /etc/php5/cli/
total 68
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     9 Apr 24  2013 conf.d -> ../conf.d
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    25 Mar 13 05:04 php.ini -> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 67629 Mar  4  2013 php.ini.old
```

I took the web server out of our load balancer pool and made some modifications.

```
$ rm /etc/php5/cli/conf.d /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

I then added a file called `check_config.php` with these contents:

```
echo("\nDefaults that are changed by or not present in ini file $path:\n");
print_r(array_diff_assoc($defaults, $ini));

echo("\nValues set by $path which differ from or are not included in the defaults:\n");
print_r(array_diff_assoc($ini, $defaults));
```

And got some delicious output.

```
$ /usr/bin/php /etc/php5/cli/check_config.php 

Defaults that are changed by or not present in ini file /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:
Array
(
    [allow_call_time_pass_reference] => 1
    [allow_url_include] => 0
    //...snip
)

Values set by /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini which differ from or are not included in the defaults:
Array
(
    [engine] => 1
    [asp_tags] => 
    //...snip
)
```

This did what I wanted, but it has a lot of red herrings - a lot of directives have a default value but are not included in the ini file and similarly a lot of module specific directives that are not in the values returned by `ini_get_all()`. I suppose I could improve this a bit by further finagling the config setups to enable more modules which should get their directives included in the list, but there are rather a lot of modules, so I think I'm good for now.

Comment: I have discovered a major shortcoming of this is that [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) returns empty strings for values that are `Off`, null, `false`, or `no`, indistinguishable from values that actually are empty strings. This appears to have been fixed in PHP 5.6.1 with `INI_SCANNER_TYPED` value, but alas this web server is using an older version than that.